# Having trouble randomizing the generation of branches on a node geometry tree

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm having trouble generating random branch generation using generative geometry - can someone look at this file and tell me what I am missing?

[image: image one]
[image: image two]

Can't seem to get the base branch arrangement to vary from instance to instance

Comment: heree is a link to the file. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/06i174lq5cnt7b5zpmfdr/basic-tree.blend?rlkey=pa391soaue0uqi47s2fcxsa5k&dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the leaves, you could, e.g. append random rotation like this:

[image]

the same principle you can use for the branches:

[image]

also you should use random scale as well.

So for every instance you can use this.

Hope it helps.